# Delete starting with fa- and ending with [ in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

My strings like this: ` fa-adjust [&#xf042;],  fa-adn [&#xf170;],  fa-align-center [&#xf037;],  fa-align-justify [&#xf039;],  fa-align-left [&#xf036;],  fa-align-right [&#xf038;],  fa-ambulance [&#xf0f9;],  fa-anchor [&#xf13d;]`

I want to delete strings between `fa-` and `[`characters by using Notepad++. I tried to delete it just like this pattern : `\[ fa^ []+\]`, `(?< fa-).*(? [)`, `(fa-)\d+( [)` and `.* fa-(\d+) [`. But it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search

```
   (?<=fa\-).*?(?=\[)
```

replace with nothing

I think this should do it

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

Search for `fa-.*?\[` in Regular expression mode. Replace with an empty string.

---

If you'd like to keep everything between the '-' and the '[':

Search for `fa-(.*?)\[`. Replace with `\1[`. This will keep everything inside the parentheses.